# IPC shared memory vs posix shared memory

Tags: c++, c, posix, ipc, shared-memory

I am currently implementing a small C function that uses posix shared memory (`shm_open()`, `ftruncate()`, `mmap()` and `shm_unlink()`.

The problem I am facing is that normaly my application exists gracefully and my cleanup routine calls `shm_unlink()`.

But if my process got `kill -9` I am facing the issue that the shm segment is still there. My application uses `fork()` and can even be started in several instances. So, if during startup I detect there is a shared memory segment, how can I decide if it is a leftover from a crash, so I can reset it or some other process may be still using it?

In SystemV IPC shared memory set of function, once I do a `shmget()` and a subsequent `shmat()` I have `shm_nattch`.

Is there something similar with posix shared memory?

Comment: Maybe you can intercept the signal with a handler and exit gracefully?

Comment: Some sort of heartbeat system would be the only thing I can think of. Maybe store a list of active PIDs in the shm segment, and poll them to make sure they're still alive?

Comment: @webuster you can't intercept `SIGKILL`, which is what `kill -9` raises

Comment: Hmmm... it seems then that **System V IPC Shared Memory** is better designed?

Answer (score 3):

POSIX shared memory is actually a variation of mapped memory. The major differences are to use shm_open() to open the shared memory object (instead of calling open()) and use shm_unlink() to close and delete the object (instead of calling close() which does not remove the object). The options in shm_open() are substantially fewer than the number of options provided in open().

IPC Shared Memory is an efficeint means of passing data between programs. One program will create a memory portion which other processes (if permitted) can access.

IMHO, the difference between them is not huge or even large since POSIX shared memory is just latter and more standard implementation of shared memory concept. The kill -9 problem is really problem. You cannot setup any handler and even atexit is not called. But you can set handler for SIGTERM and terminate your process with command:

```
kill -SIGTERM <pid>
```

Sample code for atexit and signal handler:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <system_error>
#include <iostream>

static sigset_t theMask;

static void
signalWrapper(
    int         theSignalNumber,
    siginfo_t*  theSignalDescription,
    void*       theUserContext)
{
  if (theSignalNumber == SIGTERM)
  {
    std::cerr << "Clear shared memory and exit" << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  // Reinstall handler (usefull for other signals)
  struct ::sigaction sa;
  sa.sa_sigaction = &signalWrapper;
  sa.sa_mask = theMask;
  sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;

  try
  {
    if (::sigaction(theSignalNumber, &sa, NULL) == -1)
      throw std::error_code(errno, std::system_category());
  }
  catch (const std::error_code& ec)
  {
    std::cerr << ec << std::endl;
  }
}

void
setupSignalHandlers()
{
  struct ::sigaction sa;

  // Prepare mask
  sigemptyset(&theMask);
  sigaddset(&theMask, SIGTERM);
  // Add some more if you need it to process

  sa.sa_mask      = theMask;
  sa.sa_flags     = SA_SIGINFO;
  sa.sa_sigaction = &signalWrapper;

  // Perform setup
  try
  {
    if (::sigaction(SIGTERM, &sa, NULL) == -1)
      throw std::error_code(errno, std::system_category());
  }
  catch (const std::error_code& ec)
  {
    std::cerr << ec << std::endl;
  }
}

void
bye()
{
  std::cout << "Bye!" << std::endl;
}

int
main()
{
  std::cout << "Set handler!" << std::endl;
  setupSignalHandlers();
  if (std::atexit(bye))
  {
    std::cerr << "Failed to register atexit" << std::endl;
    return 2;
  }

  std::cout << "Emit SIGTERM signals" << std::endl;
  kill(getpid(), SIGTERM);
  sleep(100);

  return 0;
}
```

Another interesting approach is **shm_unlink()** right after **shm_open()** and use of *O_CLOEXEC*. I wrote small code sample to illustrate use of unlink and POSIX shared memory reopen:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>

#include <system_error>
#include <iostream>

// Simple ShMem with RAII
struct ShMem
{
  ShMem(
    const std::string& theName)
  : _handle(-1),
    _mode(S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR),
    _name(theName)
  {
    // Here we try to create the object with exclusive right to it
    // If the object exists - it must fail.
    // File opened as 0600. The open mode might be set with
    // class enum and additional paramter to constructor
    if ((_handle = shm_open(_name.c_str(), O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_EXCL, _mode)) < 0)
    {
      std::cerr << strerror(errno) << std::endl;

      std::cout << "File " << _name << "exists. Try to reopen it!" << std::endl;
      if ((_handle = shm_open(_name.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, _mode)) < 0)
      {
        std::cerr << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        throw std::error_code(errno, std::system_category());
      }
      else
        std::cout << _name << " reopened OK";
    }
    else
      std::cout << _name << " created OK";

    // Unlink but keep descriptor
    shm_unlink(_name.c_str());
  }

 ~ShMem()
  {
  }

  const int
  handle()
  {
    return _handle;
  }

private:

  int         _handle;
  mode_t      _mode;
  std::string _name;
};
```

With *O_CLOEXEC* you can remove **shm_unlink()** at all and see what happens on **kill -9** .

Comment: Thanks, I am giving this a try. In addition to that I am also using posix semaphores (sem_open())  to protect my shared memory segment. So I suppose for the semaphore I shall follow the same approach.

Comment: I discovered once you did a shm_unlink() a parallel process call shm_open with O_CREAT | O_EXCL will not fail but create a brand new shm segment so the information I write into shm is not transported across processes. Also all non O_CREAT shm_open() calls will fail after I did the shm_unlink.

Comment: Hmm. Ok You can try to combine O_CLOEXEC with your create flags and see what happens. The shm_unlink() must go to destructor then.

Comment: @Tanuki I do not follow you on the O_CLOEXEC. What I do in my code is shm_open(), ftruncate() and mmap(). After the mmap() I am closing my file descriptor. So you mean I should do an fcntl() with O_CLOEXEC?  By the way, I put shm_unlink() to my desctructor, and on SIGINT and SIGTERM the destructor got invoked, The only problem left is now a crash or a kill -9.

Comment: I tried shm_open(_name.c_str(), O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_EXCL | O_CLOEXEC, _mode) and it worked oet on my system. It means that you can enable O_CLOEXEC right on creation.

Comment: I have tried the O_CLOEEXEC but I do not see the benefit. Can you post your code here once again?